# Remove one layer of naming in multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

Comparing the following arrays:

```
> str(arr)
 num [1:77, 1:65, 1:40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:77] "2020-04-15T00:29:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:33:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:43:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:48:00.000000000+00:00" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:65] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:40] "v_1" "v_2" "v_3" "v_4" ...
```

```
> str(arr1)
 num [1:77, 1:65, 1:40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ mynano  : chr [1:77] "2020-04-15T00:29:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:33:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:43:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:48:00.000000000+00:00" ...
  ..$ mycat   : chr [1:65] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ values  : chr [1:40] "v_1" "v_2" "v_3" "v_4" ...
```

You can see `arr1` has an additional layer of name, namely: `mynano`, `mycat`, and `values`, whereas `arr` does not.

How can I remove these names from `arr1`, while keeping the dimnames below it, as in `arr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, the `dimnames` of your array is a named list, so you have to remove the names of this list:

```
names(dimnames(arr1)) <- NULL
```